# WiFi adaptor on Lenovo T440 touchpad laptop on Ubuntu 18.04.2 is not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo T440 Thinkpad laptop. WiFi on Windows 10 works fine but on Ubuntu 18.04.2 it's showing the WiFi connections but not working despite providing id/password.

Output of `nmcli d`:

```
Device    Type      State         Connection 
wlp3s0    wifi      disconnected   -- 
enp0s25   ethernet  unavailable    -- 
lo        loopback  unmanaged      --

$ sudo lshw -short -class network 
H/W Path        Device      Class     Description 
/0/100/19       enp0s25     network   ethernet connection I218-LM 
/0/100/lc.1/0   wlp3s0      network   wirless 7260

$ networkctl status 
Warning System - networkd is not running, output will be incomplete 
. state: n/a

$ rfkill 
ID  Type       Device                 Soft      Hard 
0   bluetooth  tpacpi_bluetooth_sw    blocked   unblocked 
2   wlan       phyo                   unblocked unblocked

$ ls -1 /etc/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf 

$ dmesg | grep -E wlp3s0
[    4. 865173]  iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6. 307818]  IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    6. 543756]  IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    6. 617398]  IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready

$ lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "network Controller"
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation wireless 7260 [8086:c270]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C network | grep -i "Wireless interface" -A12 -B1`:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 7260
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlp3s0
version: 83
serial: 28:b2:bd:7b:ef:3f
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm mst pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-15 generic firmware=17.948900127.0 latency=0 link=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq: 49 memory: f0400000-f0401fff
```

Output of `ip link | grep -A2 wlp3s0`:

```
3: wlp3s0: <NO CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode link/ether 28:b2:bd:7b:ef:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

How do I use WiFi properly?

@Marmayogi, I'm available between 1030am to 0300pm from Monday to Thursday. Please suggest date and time to join chatroom.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli d`, 2. `sudo lshw -short -class network`, 3. `networkctl status` and  4. `rfkill`, 5. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Hi Marmayogi, I recently installed the Ubuntu on my laptop on Lenovo T440 Thinkpad laptop. Wifi on Windows 10 works fine but on Ubuntu 18.04.2 it's not working despite providing id/password.
output of commands you shared are stated below
nmcli d=
Device          Type               State                    Connection
wlp3s  0          wifi                  disconnected        --
enp0s25        ethernet         unavailable             --
lo                   loopback        unmanaged           --

Comment: Continued..... 
sudo lshw -short -class network
H/W Path             Device              Class             Description
/0/100/19              enp0s25           network         ethernet connection I218-LM
/0/100/lc.1/0         wlp3s0              network         wirless 7260

networkctl status
Warning System - networkd is not running, output will be incomplete
. state: n/a

Comment: Continued.....
rfkill
ID Type             Device                              Soft               Hard
0     bluetooth    tpacpi_bluetooth_sw         blocked        unblocked
2     wlan            phyo                                 unblocked     unblocked

ls -1 /etc/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.cong

Please help as I cannot use wifi...

Kind regards
Asif Khan

Comment: Instead of pasting the output of commands in the `comments`, please post it into your question by editing it . Use  `edit` option under the question by clicking it! It is really unreadable from comments!

Comment: Your WiFi is in `disconnected` state but at the same time WiFi interface card `wirless 7260` has been detected with device name `wlp3s0`. Let us find out the status of Wi-Fi driver and NM. Please post output of following commands: 1. `dmesg | grep -E wlp3s0` 2. `lspci -knn | grep -A4 -i "Network controller"` and 3. `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that WiFi driver is not loaded because the message `Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi` is missing from the output of `lspci` command. Moreover `dmesg` command also confirms that `wlp3s0: link is not ready`. Is the network card disabled? To enable Wi-Fi, run command `sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 up`. Now please post the output of commands `sudo lshw -C network | grep -i "Wireless interface" -A12 -B1`and `ip link | grep -A2 wlp3s0`. Thanks.

Comment: [Chatroom for extended discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93756/discussion-on-question-by-asif-khan-wifi-adaptor-on-lenovo-t440-touchpad-laptop).

Comment: @AsifKhan, please enter into chat session by clicking above link provided by `Seth`. I have been waiting...